# nano command has a problem

Tags: command-line, nano

The command

```
nano /etc/bind/named.conf.local
```

produces the error message:

```
The 'nano' application is not installed. You can 
install it by typing: apt-get install nano
```

If I type `apt-get install nano` the nano app still isn't installed. What should I do?

Comment: What message did you get when you typed `apt-get install nano`?  Try `sudo apt install nano` instead.

Comment: Also, run `sudo apt update` _first_ to make sure you connect to repositories and that you have the current list of what's available.

Comment: Is it on Ubuntu? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nano
```

Answer (score 0):

The command requires the package `nano` to be installed

Try installing it by using the commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nano
```

In case that didn't work out for you, you can still use `vim` or `gedit` in place the place of `nano`